# Separating String on invisible character (tab, carriage return, group separator, etc)?

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

I am trying to split a String in an Android app on certain characters. The characters are pound sign, comma, semicolon, tab, carriage return, group separator, unit separator, and record separator.

Here's how I'm doing the splitting:

```
private ArrayList<String> splitdata(String data, String delimiter){
    ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0; int previous = 0; int index = 0;
    boolean first = true;
    while (i != -1) {
        i = data.indexOf(delimiter,i);

        if(i != -1){
            if (first) {
                fields.add(data.substring(0, i));
                first = false;
            } else {
                fields.add(data.substring(previous + delimiter.length(), i));
            }
            Log.d(SCANNED_INTENT_TAG,"Newly found field: " + fields.get(index));
            index++;
            previous = i;
            i += delimiter.length();
        }
    }
    if (previous < (data.length()-1) && !first) {
        fields.add(data.substring(previous+1));
        Log.d(SCANNED_INTENT_TAG,"Newly found field: " + fields.get(index));
    }
    return fields;
}
```

This works for visible characters that I can enter from the keyboard, such as the pound sign, comma, and semicolon. However, I cannot get it to detect the special characters tab, carriage return, group separator, unit separator, or record separator. I'm passing them in like this:

```
some_arraylist = splitdata(some_str,"\t");
some_arraylist = splitdata(some_str,"\r");
some_arraylist = splitdata(some_str,Character.toString((char) 31));
some_arraylist = splitdata(some_str,Character.toString((char) 29));
some_arraylist = splitdata(some_str,Character.toString((char) 28));
```

What should I be passing them in as?

Comment: Why not just use String.split or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you aware of it but the String class already has a split function that accepts regex and will return your split string data as a String array. Looking at your code, it seems like you are not doing anything different from what split would do. Furthermore, the split function handles regex which is really powerful and really complex to implement yourself. Use the tried and true method already included in the JDK.